# Javascript text filtering

Tags: javascript

I need to block some key words using java script it worked but once it show the alert message the message will still submit, i need it to disable the submit button or better still never send the message until the spam work is remove

```
function spam_check() { 
    var value = document.getElementsByName('chat_message')[0].value;  var blocked = /sex|fuck|.tk|kiss|@yahoo|@gmail|@hotmail|.gl|.lu|.fly|.co|Earn/gi;    
    var validation = value.match(blocked);   
    if (validation) { document.getElementsByName('chat_message')[0].value = "";document.write("Hey :user:, don't try to spam") }}`
```

Here is my Form

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="chat_message" value=""/>
    <input name="submit" type="Submit" onClick="spam_check();"/>
</form>
```

Comment: FYI this could easily be turned off (editing the source of the page using firebug or similar) or indeed if js is turned off. Unlikely in this case as it's possible that your chat room works on js. Also you're checking to see if certain words are blocked, be aware the word `sussex` contains the "illegal" word `sex`, similarly `Earning` would be blocked.

Comment: Yes just now is it also block anything ends with selected words

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to prevent the @email input as well as the .{domain} input. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions